# Extract name from a html

Tags: regex, perl

Hello I know there are some modules in perl to extract tags from html source files but I need to extract this quicly: `Name CA. THAKRAR UTSAV SUBHASH`.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ8mY1/1

Comment: Why don't you try a html parser?

Answer (score 0):

```
<b>(Name)<\/b>.*?<b>(?!<\/font>|:)(.*?)<\/b>
```

Try this . See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ8mY1/3

Answer (score 0):

Always use an HTML Parser for parsing html.

The following uses [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) to find the value for which you're searching.  For a helpful 8 minute introductory video to this module, check out [Mojocast Episode 5](http://mojocasts.com/e5).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do {local $/; <DATA>});

for my $td($dom->find('td')->each) {
    next if $td->all_text ne 'Name';

    my $next = $td;
    while ($next = $next->next_sibling) {
        last if $next->node eq 'tag' and $next->all_text !~ /^[[:punct:]\s]*$/;
    }

    print $next->all_text, "\n";
}

__DATA__
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0">
<meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
<title>Member Card The Institute of Chartered Accountants of India</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 <!-- var win=null; function NewWindow(mypage,myname,w,h,scroll,pos){ if(pos=="random"){LeftPosition=(screen.width)?Math.floor(Math.random()*(screen.width-w)):100;TopPosition=(screen.height)?Math.floor(Math.random()*((screen.height-h)-75)):100;} if(pos=="center"){LeftPosition=(screen.width)?(screen.width-w)/2:100;TopPosition=(screen.height)?(screen.height-h)/2:100;} else if((pos!="center" && pos!="random") || pos==null){LeftPosition=0;TopPosition=20} settings='width='+w+',height='+h+',top='+TopPosition+',left='+LeftPosition+',scrollbars='+scroll+',location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no'; win=window.open(mypage,myname,settings);} // --> 
</script>
<script language="JavaScript1.1">
 <!-- Original: Vivek Gupta --> <!-- Begin function right(e) { if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape' && (e.which == 3 || e.which == 2)) return false; else if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' && (event.button == 2 || event.button == 3)) { alert("Sorry, you do not have permission to right click."); return false; } return true; } document.onmousedown=right; document.onmouseup=right; if (document.layers) window.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); if (document.layers) window.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP); window.onmousedown=right; window.onmouseup=right; // End --> 
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ECFFFF">
<p align="center"><u><i><b><font size="5">Members Details as on
Date</font></b></i></u></p>
<hr>
<div align="right">
<table border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="13%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Membership No.</b></font></td>
<td width="2%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>:</b></font></td>
<td width="25%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>140337,&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></font> <b><font color="#FF0000" size="3">ACTIVE</font></b></td>
<td width="8%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Sex</b></font></td>
<td width="1%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>:</b></font></td>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>M</b></font></td>
<td width="13%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Date of Birth</b></font></td>
<td width="1%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>:</b></font></td>
<td width="38%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>30/12/1986</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="13%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Name</b></font></td>
<td width="2%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>:</b></font></td>
<td width="25%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>CA. THAKRARUTSAV SUBHASH</b></font></td>
<td width="8%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Blood Grp</b></font></td>
<td width="1%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>:</b></font></td>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>B (-)</b></font></td>
<td width="13%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Enrolment Dt.</b></font></td>
<td width="1%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>:</b></font></td>
<td width="38%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>29/07/2011</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="13%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Asso.&nbsp; / Fellow</b></font></td>
<td width="2%" bgcolor="#99CCFF">:</td>
<td width="25%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>ACA</b></font></td>
<td width="8%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Nationality</b></font></td>
<td width="1%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"></td>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>IND</b></font></td>
<td width="13%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>FellowDate</b></font></td>
<td width="1%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>:</b></font></td>
<td width="38%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>&nbsp;</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="13%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Father's Name</b></font></td>
<td width="2%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>:</b></font></td>
<td width="25%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>SUBHASH THAKRAR</b></font></td>
<td width="8%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"></td>
<td width="1%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"></td>
<td width="18%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"></td>
<td width="13%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><b><font size="2">COP Status</font></b></td>
<td width="1%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><b>:</b></td>
<td width="27%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>FULLTIME</b></font></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<hr>
<div align="right">
<table border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><u><font size="2"><b>Professional Address Details</b></font></u></td>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><u><font size="2"><b>Residential Address Details</b></font></u></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" colspan="2"></td>
<td width="50%" colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>OPP PUNJAB NATIONAL BANK</b></font></td>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>M/S CHATRABHUJ SAVJI &amp; CO</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>SUTARWADA</b></font></td>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>SUTARWADA</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>&nbsp;</b></font></td>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>&nbsp;</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>&nbsp;</b></font></td>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>&nbsp;</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>PORBANDAR - 360575</b></font></td>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>PORBANDAR - 360575</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>INDIA</b></font></td>
<td width="50%" colspan="2" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>INDIA</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="14%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Tel. No.</b></font></td>
<td width="36%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>0286-2243863</b></font></td>
<td width="14%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Tel. No.</b></font></td>
<td width="34%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>0286 2245641</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="14%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Fax. No.</b></font></td>
<td width="36%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>&nbsp;</b></font></td>
<td width="14%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Fax. No.</b></font></td>
<td width="34%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>&nbsp;</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="14%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Mob. No.</b></font></td>
<td width="36%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>09409059418</b></font></td>
<td width="14%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>Mob. No.</b></font></td>
<td width="34%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>09409059418</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="14%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>E-mail.</b></font></td>
<td width="36%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>usthakrar@gmail.com</b></font></td>
<td width="14%" bgcolor="#CCCCFF"><font size="2"><b>E-mail.</b></font></td>
<td width="34%" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><font size="2"><b>usthakrar@gmail.com</b></font></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<hr>
<div align="right">
<table border="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<td width="29%"><a href="locm_res.asp?MRH_MRN=140337" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'mywin','500','400','no','center');return false" onfocus="this.blur()"><b><font color="#0000FF">Member Employment Details</font></b></a></td>
<td width="27%"><a href="locm_ocp.asp?MRH_MRN=140337" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'mywin','900','400','no','center');return false" onfocus="this.blur()"><b><font color="#0000FF">Member Firm Association Details</font></b></a></td>
<td width="44%"><b><a href="locm_article.asp?MRH_MRN=140337" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'mywin','900','400','yes','center');return false" onfocus="this.blur()"><font color="#0000FF">Article / Audit (List of Student undergoing Training with details)</font></a></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="29%">.</td>
<td width="27%"></td>
<td width="44%">.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%" colspan="3" align="center"><b><a href="firm_approval.asp" onclick="NewWindow(this.href,'mywin','900','400','yes','center');return false" onfocus="this.blur()"><font color="#0000FF">Search Firm Registered / Approved with ICAI as on Date</font></a></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
CA. THAKRARUTSAV SUBHASH
```